# How many circles do 11 points define?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, circles, combinatorial-geometry

I came across this question in my class:

> There are 11 different points in the plane with no 3 points are on the same line.
>   a) How many circles do these points define? (Points define a circle if there is a unique circle through those points.)
>   b) How many circles would they define, if 4 points were on the same line?

I think, that we just need 2 points, to define a circle (one for the centre and 1 for the radius). In that case a) would be $11\times10=110$ different circles, however that seems to be incorrect.

How would you solve it?

Comment: Nope, try with 3 points.

Comment: Wait, are there 11 or 12 points?

Comment: @TheDeadLegend why 3 points?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Taxel yea, it is 11 points, i fixed the title

Comment: Are all $11$ points allowed to be on the same circle? The answer would be different vs. the case where no $4$ points are concyclic.

Comment: @dxiv the question doesn´t specify this case, so i guess there are no concyclic points.

Comment: @WannaBeGnome If the question doesn't specify it, you can't assume it just because it's easier to solve it that way. In that case, the answer would not be a single number, but a set (or range) of possible numbers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't take two points to define a circle, because either of those two points could be the centre. Instead, the solution for part (a) is simply $\binom{11}3=165$ because three non-collinear points uniquely define a circle (assuming that multiplicity is counted, or that no four points are concyclic; if such a quartet existed the number of *distinct* circles would be lower).

For part (b), $\binom43=4$ circles become degenerate and need to be subtracted, so the answer is 161 circles in this case (again, with one of the assumptions above).

Comment: I agree with $\binom{11}{3}$ but it still seems like you can create two circles per pair as described by the OP which would add $2\cdot \binom{11}{2}$ to this total.

Comment: A family of circle is described about 2 points. To get a particular circle, we need 3 points @law-of-fives

Comment: @TheDeadLegend yes, of course, I understand. Sometimes I'm slow!

Comment: Thanks. I didn´t realise that 2 points aren't enough to define a circle. Thanks for an explanation.

Comment: @WannaBeGnome, for clarity, 2 points is *enough* to define a circle if you add some extra rules like which to take as a centre or how to define the radius. However, your own questions states "Points define a circle if there is a unique circle **through** those points", so then you need 3 points to uniquely define a circle.

Comment: @Wolfie I added the definition. I had to argue with someone over it, and I won out because if any two-point definition was used the solution would be the same between (a) and (b), which would not likely be wanted.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Ah sorry, I didn't look at the edit history. As ever in maths, forming a sufficiently accurate question is half the battle!

Comment: Two points IS enough to define a circle, by saying that the leftmost point is the centre, and in case of a tie the topmost point is.

Comment: @orlp ...did you read Wolfie's first comment upstream?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $3$ points define a circle

$^{11}C_3$ for case 1 because no three in same line

$^{11}C_3-^4C_3$ for case 2, to exclude cases taking three points  from those 4 collinear points

Comment: (taking them to be 11 points in total)